# How to change tokenizer in elasticsearch in the existing index

Tags: indexing, tokenize

I have the following problem:
I have an index of 30 million documents the mapping as follows:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:8080/xxxxx/yyyyy/_mapping?pretty=true -d '{"xxxxx":{"_id":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"properties":{"content":
{"type":"string","store":"no"},"title":{"type":"string","index":"no"},"created_date":{"type":"integer","index":"not_analyzed"},"url":
{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"author":{"type":"string","index":"no"},"author_url":{"type":"string","index":"no"},"domain":
{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},"lang":{"type":"string","index":"no"}}}}'
```

Tokenizer is not selected in the settings, so apply a standard.
I would like to request "facets" to create ranking links(url) in field "content". Unfortunately I can not do that because the standard tokenizer shared links (url) to pieces.
Question:
Can an existing index without reindexing change the tokenizer, so that new documents added to the index handle the new tokenizer (uax_url_email) and old documents remain unchanged.

I tried that:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:8080/xxxxx -d '{
  "settings" : {
    "index": {
      "analysis" :{
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type" : "custom",
            "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
            "filter" : "lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

but I get an error:
`{"error": "IndexAlreadyExistsException [[xxxxx] Already exists]", "status": 400}`

Is there another way to not reindex with query "facets" to create ranking links (url)?

Thank you in advance of any help

Answer (score 1):

Try next, for existing index "xxxxx"

```
curl -XPUT localhost:8080/xxxxx/_settings -d '{
      "analysis" :{
        "analyzer": {
          "default": {
            "type" : "custom",
            "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
            "filter" : "lowercase"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Be sure your elasticseach port is 8080, by default it 9200

Comment: When tryin this approach on 7.0 i get "error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter, index.analysis.analyzer.default.type, index.analysis.analyzer.default.tokenizer]] for open indices [[regular/DPOGzbSwSLqtMmBzqWAq5Q]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter, index.analysis.analyzer.default.type, index.analysis.analyzer.default.tokenizer]] for open indices [[regular/DPOGzbSwSLqtMmBzqWAq5Q]]"},"status":400}

Comment: You must close indice, make a change and open again. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html